# Draw on canvas rectangles of different colors

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to draw two rectangles of different colors:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.beginPath();
context.drawImage(this,0,0);
context.beginPath();
context.rect(left1,top1,width1,height1);
context.lineWidth = 8;
context.strokeStyle = 'red';
context.stroke();
context.rect(left2,top2,width2,height2);
context.lineWidth = 8;
context.strokeStyle = 'green';
context.stroke();
```

But both come out the same color (green, which is the second color chosen).

I guess that `stroke` doesn't do what I expect it to do.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick is that you simply need to call `context.beginPath()` before creating the second square.

Although not strictly needed, you should also completely close your paths with `context.closePath()` as well (which is called *before* `context.stroke()`).

I've added both `context.beginPath()` and `context.closePath()` to the following example:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
//context.beginPath();
//context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
context.beginPath();
context.rect(30, 30, 30, 30); /* Modified */
context.lineWidth = 8;
context.strokeStyle = 'red';
context.closePath();
context.stroke();
context.beginPath(); /* Added */
context.rect(80, 30, 30, 30); /* Modified */
context.lineWidth = 8;
context.strokeStyle = 'green';
context.closePath();
context.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="150" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</canvas>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I think you are confused about `closePath` and what it does. It is not an *end path* but just a lineTo last movedTo point, to transform an open path in a closed one (like two lines in a triangle).A rect is already a closed shape, so `closePath` is completely useless here.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this example

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

// Red rectangle
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth = "6";
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.rect(5, 5, 290, 140); 
ctx.stroke();

// Green rectangle
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth = "4";
ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
ctx.rect(30, 30, 50, 50);
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150">
```